# PHP / OpenCart 2.2.0 - Creating custom theme

Tags: php, opencart2.x

i'm starting today with theme development in OpenCart 2.2 and i'm following this article:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-introduction--cms-21786

Wich uses the 1.5.6.1 version of opencart. (I can't find nothing about this for version 2.2, so i assumed it must be the same).

As a i understand we should create the theme directory in catalog/view/theme. For test pourposes i created a "customtheme" directory and copied the dir structure from the default theme.

The problem is that when i go to dashboard -> settings -> general -> Theme, the selectbox doesn't show the new theme i created.

What am i doing wrong?
Should i just modify the default theme? it doesnt seem to be the best path to follow.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you copied all the files from default theme into your new folder? What is the exact path of your customtheme?

Comment: You don't need to copy any files into your fresh theme. In the beginning it can be completely empty. No problem. It uses a build in fallback method going back to the default theme if a file is not included.

Comment: This is OpenCart 2 Theme development tutorials Written by myself . http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/11/opencart-2-theme-development/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when duplicating the default theme into a folder named **duplicate**, so I looked into the code. The admin extension for theme actually looks for a controller for the new theme which I didn't have; so what I did were

Duplicate the default theme controller (*theme_default.php*) under **/admin/controller/theme/** into **theme_duplicate.php** and named the controller **ControllerThemeThemeDuplicate**

Replace all the keys **theme_default** with **theme_duplicate**

Duplicate the default view admin/view/template/theme/theme_default.tpl and named it theme_duplicate.tpl

I also duplicated the **language file** and named it **theme_duplicate.php**. I also updated a couple of texts inside the new duplicated language file.

Now if you look into the Extensions/Modifications/theme, you will see your new theme and it should so also be ready to be updated under settings

Comment: thanks i'll try that. I'll up vote the answer if it works and when i test that. Thanks anyway. ;)

Comment: I did this and it kind of works but I have an issue. If I go to Settings->Theme and select the default theme and then go to Extensions->Themes->edit default theme and change the Theme Directory to my custom theme directory then the new theme is reflected in the front end. However if I install my new theme under Extensions->Themes and make sure the Theme Directory is set to the custom theme directory and then go to Settings->Theme and change it to the custom theme then the front end reflects the default theme. What have I missed? Thanks

Comment: The controller thing did it. Opencart sucks big time if such non-obvious things aren't even mentioned in their [documentation](http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the custom theme was not available in the dashboard -> settings -> general -> Theme. I found a detailed solution here: http://undefined.gr/site/2016/10/09/custom-opencart-2-3-0-2-theme .

Answer (score 0):

You should paste all the files from `catalog/view/theme/default/template` into `catalog/view/theme/default/customtheme`. The `template` folder should be present there.

Comment: See my comment on the first post. No need to copy all files into your new theme. Uses fallback to default theme when file not found.

Comment: Yes @Klaus, i'm aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie in opencart who got into this problem after watching the tutorial and downloading opencart 2.3.x, I read that they moved the theme changing thing to

`Extensions >> Extensions >> Themes (in the drop down menu) >> Edit >> Theme Directory`.

Hope this helps a future theme creator who comes here all confused.