# How-to create and install a custom theme in Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, css, themes, opencart, customization

I have been searching for documentation on how to create a custom theme in Opencart 2.3.x but this seems to be limited (or non-existent). I have found a couple of posts here but none of them answer the specific issue I'm seeing, which has been raised by others such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137603/php-opencart-2-2-0-creating-custom-theme/41377535#41377535) (see comment by @Bollis).

In Opencart 2.3.x it appears themes work slightly differently to previously. Here's what I have done in line with recommendations on how to create a custom theme:

1. **Duplicate the default theme controller** (theme_default.php) under /admin/controller/extension/theme/ to theme_mythemename.php and named the controller class ControllerThemeThemeMythemename - replaced all theme_default occurrences within the file to theme_mythemename.
2. **Duplicate the default view** admin/view/template/extension/theme/theme_default.tpl and named it theme_mythemename.tpl - again, replaced all theme_default occurrences within the file to theme_mythemename.
3. **Duplicate the default language file** in admin/language/extension/theme/theme_default.php and named it theme_mythemename.php - again, replaced all 'default' occurrences within the file to 'mythemename'.
4. **Made a copy of /catalog/view/theme/default** directory to mythemename.
5. **Edit catalog/view/theme/mythemename/template/common/header.tpl** so that it points to the correct 'copied' stylesheet rather than the default `<link href="catalog/view/theme/mythemename/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">`

I then installed the theme under Extensions > Themes, enabled it and ensured the directory is set to mythemename. Under my store I then also selected it as the theme. The result is that the default theme still seems to load - I can see in the DOM explorer that it's still loading the default stylesheet and also changes to header.tpl in mythemename are not reflected. It's strange, as if I don't *install* the theme and I modify the Default Store Theme to point to mythemename directory, all works. But, I want to create a new theme, not modify the default theme.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The post by @Андрей Литвиненко in the above link worked for me. It looks like this a bug and prevents theme directories other than default from working.

Comment: No it's not a bug - you just need to understand the way to create a new theme.  I will follow up with a detailed explanation if I get time.

Comment: That would be appreciated. There doesn't seem to be anything in the docs.